# Can flume, spark, storm read from Kafka in round-robin way?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, flume, apache-storm, round-robin

I have 3 partitions: 0, 1, 2. So the messages can be classified as 0, 1, 2.

eg:

1 message in partition 0: 0

3 messages in partition 1: 111

2 messages in partition 2: 22

How to make the consumer to consume messages in the order 012x12x1x (x means no messages at that time). The order of consumed messages look like: 012121. 
I would like to do this in both C++ and Python. Looking into the existing clients, messages can be produced in round-robin fashion, but can not be consumed in round-robin fashion.

Any idea?

There is partition.assignment.strategy in Kafka consumer configs (http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#consumerconfigs). I am looking for some tools which implements this config (**such as flume, spark, storm**) to read data from kafka, reorder them, and write to kafka again. Continue the above example. The re-ordered messages look like:
012121 (012x12x1x)

**UPDATE**

Now, I can do this in C++ Kafka Client (**https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka**).

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        RdKafka::Message *msg = m_consumer->consume(m_topic, i, 1000);
        // Do something about msg here...
    }
```

Output:

```
Reading from 1=>4953---1---
Reading from 0=>46164---0---
Reading from 1=>4954---1---
Reading from 0=>46165---0---
Reading from 1=>4955---1---
Reading from 0=>46166---0---
Reading from 1=>4956---1---
Reading from 0=>46167---0---
Reading from 1=>4957---1---
Reading from 0=>46168---0---
```

Comment: My question re-edited. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, you can use the [high level consumer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example).

If you consume from all 3 partitions in the same process, using the same `group.id`, you could create 3 worker threads that act as consumers, and cycle between them in a round-robin fashion.

I understand that you explicitly mentioned Python and C++ as your target languages.
From my own experience in Python, there's no equivalent to the high level consumer provided in Java.

So you could either wrap it somehow, like creating a new Java process that acts as a server, and consume the messages through this process, OR you could try to port the high level consumer to Python and/or C++.

Another alternative is to consume each partition, write the data to some other medium like MySQL (or any other RDBMS), and consume the messages using SQL to perform the round-robin, and eventually delete them from the relevant table.

In any case, I suggest you reconsider Kafka as your transport layer. Your requirements (consuming in a round-robin way) are not aligned with Kafka's core design / architecture. Here's why:
As long as the number of partitions is smaller than the available cores in the consumer machine - then one can consume the messages on that single (!) machine in a round robin way, just like I described above.

However, Kafka is also designed for a distributed load (of the consumers). That's the motivation to create partitions to a single topic. Scalability is a key concept in Kafka.

So if you have more partitions than the available cores in the consumer machine, you may not be able to properly iterate over the partitions and consume the messages in a round robin way.

Example: say you have 20 partitions in a specific topic. This topic produces a lot of messages, all the time. Now let's say you have a single machine with 4 CPU cores to consume from that topic. By design you'll be able to consume from at most 4 partitions at a time. Transforming this to a round robin consumption can be achieved by buffering a meaningful amount of messages in memory, or some other mechanism (which might lead to other issues like latency). That's when we assume that all of the partitions are available all the time, without network issues or disk issues that have their effect on Kafka.  That's why I think that "joining back" the partitions into some other stream of messages is not a trivial thing to do in a large scale.

Comment: There is partition.assignment.strategy in Kafka consumer configs (http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#consumerconfigs). I am looking for some tools which implements this config (such as kafka logstash plugin) to read data from kafka, reorder them, and write to kafka again. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: [a] I'm not aware of such tools; [b] I'm aware of Logstash Kafka plugin, but its consumption strategy is pretty straight forward; [c] I truly think that what you try to achieve conflicts the core design decisions of Kafka. [d] Therefore I humbly suggest that you consume the data from Kafka, use some other medium like queues or RDBMS, re-order as needed, and finally push back to Kafka in a different topic.

Comment: It is possible to write my own kafka input plugin? In Java Kafka client, round-robin consuming is supported. So, this client can be used for my own plugin.

Comment: Try to do use in flume or spark or storm. Now, I am searching on the google.

Comment: There is nothing in Kafka's core design / architecture that prohibits round-robin consumption. The consumer app can simply consume M messages from N partitions per iteration depending on its need. An example of this is the new Kafka streams API that supports things like join(partitions..).

Comment: @Edenhill as long as the number of partitions is small enough - yes, one can consume the messages on a single machine in a round robin fashion, just like I described above. However, Kafka is also designed for a distributed load (of the consumers). So if you have, say, 20 partitions in a single topic, and a single machine with 4 CPU cores, then **by design** you won't be able to consume them in a pure round robin way.